# How to check check earliest date & latest date in apex class

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate

I have an object `X__c` which has 2 date fields `D1__c` & `D2__c`. There are meny records for this object `X__c`. I want to get from all records the earliest date value from `D1__c` field and latest date value from `D2__c` field. How can I achieve this in apex class and display in another date field?

Comment: See [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm). You should be able to using MIN and MAX on your date fields in a single aggregate query.

Answer (score 4):

As @KeithC mentioned, you can use aggregates for this:

```
public class DateCombination
{
    public final Date minD1;
    public final Date maxD2;
    public DateCombination(Date min, Date max)
    {
        this.minD1 = min;
        this.maxD2 = max;
    }
}
public static DateCombination getDateRange()
{
    AggregateResult all = [SELECT MIN(D1__c) minD1, MAX(D2__c) maxD2 FROM X__c];
    return new DateCombination((Date)all.get('minD1'), (Date)all.get('maxD2'));
}
```

Comment: Great that you have used a class to process this instead of just using an aggregate SOQL. Can we use a static method on a parameterized constructor ?

Comment: @Bennie Not sure I understand your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Can we write/compile a class with a parameterized constructor and without a default constructor(non-parameterized) ?

Comment: @Bennie Sure it will compile. It is valid. You just can no longer call the empty constructor. But the `DateCombination` would be meaningless in such a case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SOQL query retrieving records from the X__c table, then you can use the **order by** clause to sort your result set by the date fields. Try something like this:

```
Select Id From X__c Order By D1__c desc
```

You'll get a pretty clean and ordered list that you can grab the first and last record from, which would be the earliest/latest D1__c value.

Another alternative, if you somehow obtain a List through means other than a SOQL query (i.e. a trigger), is that you can use the sort() method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm

Check out that doc for a pretty good explanation on how you can create your own wrappers that implement the Comparable interface for custom sorting.